# Cannot read property prototype of null web driver exception is getting displayed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run selenium script which ran 100 times successfully previously. But now It is displaying the below error, there is no change in the code not even a single letter. I tried to resolve my issue in the below following ways:

As i know the issue is not with the code and i guess the issue somewhere lies between WebDriver or Chrome Driver configurations

->Updated  my chorme driver which i am using in the script  to version 81 as my chrome browser is also version 81
->Updated selenium jar to latest version. (with old version also i am facing the same issue and with the new version also i am facing the same issue)

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
    at Function.Object.create (https://gom/openiam-ui-static/js/common/openiam.common.js?3.3.1.RELEASE:8:25)
    at new CacheWithUUID (<anonymous>:85:24)
    at getPageCache (<anonymous>:247:18)
    at callFunction (<anonymous>:435:17)
    at <anonymous>:464:23
    at <anonymous>:465:3
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.92, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\5038~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57252}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: d75cb3cd1e56a69fa922c007bfe36072
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getTitle(RemoteWebDriver.java:281)
    at testclasses.Baseclass.invokeBrowser(Baseclass.java:83)
    at testclasses.NewTest.Test1(NewTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3b6eb2ec: 681 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@96532d6: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@7e0ea639: 10 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@34ce8af7: 74 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@2d6e8792: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 13 ms
```

Error log points to the if condition below for the script failure

```
if(driver.getTitle().contains(" MyAccount - Log In"))
            {
                driver.findElement(By.id("aSsoLogin")).click();             
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("id"));
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("pwd"));
                driver.findElement(By.id("submitFrm")).click();
                if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("GE Browser Security Check")) {
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Remind me later']"))));
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Remind me later']")).click();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does it specify which line is failing?  That might help narrow down the issue.  My best guess based on the information given is that it may be failing between the click of 'aSsoLogin' and clear of 'username', which could potentially be resolved by a WebDriverWait wait.until() test.

Comment: It is failing at first step in if condition check. So I commented the if condition and tried then it is failing at the second step 'assologin'  and if I comment that to it is failing at the next step and so on. At all these steps it is failing with the same error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Chrome browser automatically updated to version 81, though i used chrome driver version 81 it is failing. So i downgraded chrome browser to version 79 and used 79 version of chrome driver to run the selenium script it worked. There are issue with new version of chrome browsers(80 & 81)